# how to make a dynamic form accoring to server calls

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I'm new to React-Final-Form. I need to render some parts of the form according to what users have chosen from a drop-down menu in the form. So, there is a drop down at the beginning of the form, and when users select a country from that drop down I need to make an ajax call (via axios) and then depending on what I get as the response from the server I should render the rest of the form. Where should I make that server call?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, but the first that comes to mind, and probably the easiest, would be to use [an `<OnChange>` component](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-listeners).